# Unable to update global array in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, global-variables, react-state

I am building a React based application where I need to dynamically generate some input fields. New input fields must be added on the click of a '+' button and I should be able to delete individual fields using a 'x' icon next to each input field.

I am providing a unique id to each field using a count variable that increments on click of my '+' icon and I am making use of a global array called 'idArr' to track the id's of the field that are currently displayed. The '+' icons functionality is working alright bit in the 'x' icon, I get the following error when I am removing the index from my global array -

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.
```

I wrote a function to delete the id from the array in the following way:

```
    const removeFromArray = (id) => {
        idArr.splice(idArr.indexOf(id));
    };
```

This is how my input fields are generated:

```
    const components = idArr.map((id) =>
        <Component index={id} idArr={idArr} />
    )
```

Here the 'Component' is a custom component I am creating that contains my input field and the 'x' icon.

And here is my return function -

```
return (
   <div id={DOM_ID}> {components} </div>
)
```

Comment: Please show us the full react code as well as where you are calling `removeChild`

Comment: In React, do not use `splice`, which mutates the array, but create a new one and put it in your state. Also, do not use a global variable for this.

Comment: I was facing a similar issue while using an state variable array for this, thus trying to resolve it using a global array instead

Comment: And I am not calling the removeChild function anywhere in my code. I suspect it is being called internally by React when I am updating my array.

Comment: You need a state if you want to change anything in react https://react.dev/learn/adding-interactivity#state-a-components-memory

Answer (score 1):

Fist of all, state should be immutable in react. We will create new array using useState then we can handle this using `filter` method.

```
 const [idArr, setIdArr] = useState('put your array value here') // replace text with your array

 const removeFromArray = (id) => {
   const updatedArray = idArr.filter(item => item !== id)
   setIdArr(updatedArray);
 };
```